# Local PySpark documentation much sparser than online

Tags: pyspark

I am spinning up on Python and PySpark, installed using Anaconda on
Windows 10.  [This
tutorial](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-rename-dataframe-column/#using-structtype)
refers to a `col()` method, which I found in the following file [1]:

```
%USERPROFILE%/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/site-packages/pyspark/sql/functions.py
```

It returns a `Column` object, whose class definition I found in:

```
%USERPROFILE%/anaconda3/envs/py39/Lib/site-packages/pyspark/sql/column.py
```

However, the doc string is extremely spartan:

```
A column in a DataFrame.

.. versionadded:: 1.3.0
.. versionchanged:: 3.4.0
    Supports Spark Connect.

Examples
--------
Column instances can be created by

>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(
...      [(2, "Alice"), (5, "Bob")], ["age", "name"])

Select a column out of a DataFrame
>>> df.name
Column<'name'>
>>> df["name"]
Column<'name'>

Create from an expression

>>> df.age + 1
Column<...>
>>> 1 / df.age
Column<...>
```

In contrast, the documentation I found from Google is much
informative, e.g.,
[here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html)
and
[here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html).
It tells me that a `Column` object can contain data from a DataFrame
as well as be empty, consisting only of the column heading.

*I was under the impression that the documentation in the source
`*.py` files reflect that of the reference documentation.  **Is there
anything that I have to do to make the more detailed information
available locally?***

**Notes**

**[1]** I found the files using Cygwin Vim's folder subtree search
command:

```
:vimgrep /^\s\=\(class\|def\)\s\+col\>/
\ /c/Users/User.Name/anaconda3/envs/py39/lib/site-packages/pyspark/**.py
```

The `py39` folder is the Conda environment created for Python 3.9.  The
`pyspark` folder is what I found `%SPARK_HOME%` set to *after* setting
the following environment variables and running `pyspark` from
the Conda prompt:

```
set "HADOOP_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Hadoop\2.7.1"
set "PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=Python"
set "PYSPARK_PYTHON=Python"
set "JAVA_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\Library"
set "SPARK_HOME=%USERPROFILE%\anaconda3\envs\py39\lib\site-packages\pyspark"
```

Comment: No, there's nothing to get. A docstring is a docstring and it consists of whatever is actually written in the code. It bears no necessarily relationship to any particular external documentation source. You might as well be asking about the comments.

Comment: That tells me that I better get familiar with finding the correct authoritative online reference documentation.  Did you want to post your comment as the answer?

Comment: be sure to check the documentation for the spark version you're using. google will usually reference the latest release in its top search results.

Comment: @samkart: That's the part that worries me.  PySpark seems like an ecosystem of tools rather than one thing.  i can google (say) how to find the version of Pandas (not that I use that!) but for Spark, I'm not confident that the Spark version 3.4.1 shown upon startup helps much for a specific package, class, or method.

Comment: There are other hazards, too. The posted question cites two pages from Google, but I didn't realize that they were for Java. I dabbled in Java and am new to Python, so I just read the pages for a general idea. It wasn't until I looked at the URL that I realized it was for Java. Looking for the Python counterpart version 3.4.1 can be tricky. I started from [Spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs), went to 3.4.1, clicked `API Docs` at the top and chose `Python`, then clicked on the `Spark SQL and DataFrames` box.

Comment: This led to a hierarchy of bookmarks on the left navigation pane, from which there are two links to *different* `Column` pages.  The first provided no preamble to describe the class; on the left pane hierarchy, navigate to `Spark SQL` `->` `Column`.  The second is provides exactly the same spartan description as in the `Column` doc string; navigate to `Spark SQL` `->` `Core Classes`, and on the resulting page body, click on `Column(jc)`.

Comment: So the "official" documentation seems fragmented, and the fragment with explanatory preamble matches source file doc string. It isn't clear why the preamble is sparser for Python than Java.

Comment: I use [this master link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/) and navigate to API Docs > Python > API Reference

Comment: That's my 1st `Spark docs` link.  But the fragmentation occurs after one descends down into more specific links.  It's still a mystery why even the more explanatory page is sparser than for Java.  If I hadn't relied on the random (and incorrect) page from Google, I wouldn't have found a more complete description.